# Should there be a hyphen in the construction "IT affin"?

Tags: hyphen, hyphenation

Writing a german cover letter for a job position. In the sentence

> Ich bin eine IT affine Person - im Umgang mit Excel und ...

should there be a hyphen between *IT* and *affin*? What would be the rule here? I am hesitant between the following possibilities:

> IT affin
>
> IT-affin
>
> It affin
>
> It-affin
>
> it affin
>
> it-affin

Where I am quite sure, that it should be in all caps, I am not sure about the hyphen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Only

> Ich bin eine **IT-affine** Person.

is correct. In German compounds, there is either a hyphen or nothing between the elements.

- **In no case there is a space as in English.** Though, a lot of people are doing this wrong, even on public displays. Most of them are excused for being second language speakers of German. There's even a name for this bad habit, it's called **Deppenleerzeichen** – dork space.

If there are multiple proper names connected, or if there are abbreviations inside the word, all parts must be connected with hyphens. This is called *Durchkopplung*.

> Ich bin eine **Microsoft-Apple-Linux-affine** Person.
>
> Ich bin eine **mobil-IT-affine** Person.

---

Though, your expression doesn't mean what you may think in German. Most people would assume an *IT-affine Person* is someone who is always buying the latest stuff, not necessarily knowing how to use it. It's part of your lifestyle, not part of your profession. Think *Aficionado*.

If you think it's part of your profession, you should write

> Ich kenne mich gut mit IT aus.

instead.

Comment: Are you sure you want to say *proper name* here and not just *noun?*

Comment: It's proper names. Ordinary nouns may be hyphenated, but it's not the norm.

Comment: Ah, you were talking about hyphen vs. nothing, while I thought you were talking about hyphen (and nothing) vs. space. You might want to make that more clear (in particular since the question only ponders the possibility of hyphens and spaces here).

Comment: I blame spell checkers for *Deppen leer Zeichen*.

Comment: I never use them. They make you dumb.

Comment: Interesting thought on the meaning of `IT-affine Person`. Still I feel that "Ich kenne mich gut mit IT aus" on a cover letter doesn't transport what it should, so here I would stay with "IT-affin". Maybe "Im Umgang mit IT bin ich sicher und geübt"?

Comment: Uh, whatever...

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning hat the adjectivization of nouns, as opposed to proper names, also requires lowercase: Not *ein Grasgrüner Apfel*, but *ein grasgrüner Apfel*.

Comment: The "Most of them are excused for being second language speakers of German", alas is wrong in really all its aspects. They are not excused, mostly natives, …